# Issue with changing permissions

Tags: permissions, chmod, fakeroot

I don't understand why the permission does not change for a user when I run the `chmod` command with `fakeroot`.

Initially, the file has these permissions:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  a.txt*
```

When I try to change the permission for the file using `chmod` it works fine:

```
chmod 111 a.txt

---x--x--x  a.txt*
```

When I run it with `fakeroot` it doesn't seem to do the work fine. It sets the permissions for group and other correctly, but not for the user. The permissions for read and write are set, no matter what the 1st value in `chmod` command is.

```
fakeroot chmod 111 a.txt

-rwx--x--x  a.txt*
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: [Here you can find the answer for this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/538045/issue-with-changing-permissions)

Comment: Please post the [Unix & Linux answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/538045/issue-with-changing-permissions) as an answer here and mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

From the [man](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man1/fakeroot-tcp.1.html) page:

> Here is an example session with fakeroot.  Notice that inside the 
>   fake  root  environment file manipulation that requires root
>   privileges succeeds, but is not really happening.(...) 
>   Only the effects that user joost could do anyway happen for real.

So, I guess the userid you are using only has rights to change the 'group' and 'other' settings and these changes are 'really' executed.

Comment: If your assumption is correct, why am I allowed to change the permission without using fakeroot? I am using same userid.

Comment: @SabinHarnagea You're right, Probably my explanation is not correct.